# systemd timer job not working

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I want the job to run every day at 2am and 2pm
I have this in the .timer file

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 02:00:00,14:00:00
```

But when I systemctl start myjob.timer I get this error:

```
Failed to start myjob.timer: Unit myjob.timer has a bad unit file setting.
```

I've googled, but not sure exactly where wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the complete unit file.

Comment: I removed the seconds and it worked.

Comment: I don't know why your answer was deleted. I flagged it for undeletion. If it is undeleted, just extend it a little (add the correct syntax) and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

my bad - seconds are not allowed, this worked:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-* 02:00,14:00
```